# Display dropdownlist data to textbox

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms, textbox

Hi how may i know how to display data from drop down list to textbox ? i only manage to do so for the name and id, but cant do the same for my price.

for exmaple, when i choose orange from the dropdownlist, the id, name and price will be displayed in their individual textbox. thanks !

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {
        bindDropDownList();     
    }
}

private SqlDataReader getReader()
{   
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Yasha"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

    string strCommandText = "SELECT productID, productName, productPrice from Product";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

    myConnect.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    return reader;
} 

private void bindDropDownList()
{
    ddlProduct.DataSource = getReader();
    ddlProduct.DataTextField = "productName";
    ddlProduct.DataValueField = "productID";      
    ddlProduct.DataBind();
}

protected void ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbProductID.Text = ddlProduct.SelectedValue.ToString();
    tbProduct.Text = ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Text;
    tbPrice.Text = ?;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either make a call to the db in your `SelectedIndexChanged` event, or you could persist the data returned from `getReader` (in another form - dictionary of ProductId, Price) into `ViewState` to query in your `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Personally, I'd avoid `ViewState` and make a light call to your db with the `ProductId` to get the cost.